# GCM message(Or data ) limit

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging

I have php code for sending push notification . It works for small data(message) but when i try to send large String in push notification its not working. Is there any limit on string to send in GCM ? if any what is size?

Thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit of **4096 bytes** on the payload of the message (which includes all the custom keys and values in your payload).

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts, I found that the limit of the data part of the message cannot be larger than 2048 bytes. 
The thing is, that I use UTF-8 encoding for the data, which I think could be the reason.
The data is the contents of a small text file.

```
// Prepare JSON containing the GCM message content.
JSONObject jGcmData = new JSONObject();
jGcmData.put("to", "/topics/"+args[0].trim());
// Set maximum time alive in seconds.
jGcmData.put("time_to_live", 300);
// Set the collapse key, which groups as one the messages of same topic
jGcmData.put("collapse_key", args[0].trim());
// Prepare the GCM data
JSONObject jData = new JSONObject();
String message = readFile(args[1].trim(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
jData.put("message", message);
System.out.println("Data length: " + message.length());
// Add the data to the message.
jGcmData.put("data", jData);
System.out.println("Total GCM length: " + jGcmData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8").length);
// Create connection to send GCM Message request.
URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
 // Send GCM message content.
DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
outputStream.write(jGcmData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
// Read GCM response.
InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
String resp = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
System.out.println(resp);
System.out.println("SUCCESS!");
```